# Why use initializer_list instead of vector in parameters?

Tags: c++

What is the actual benefit and purpose of `initializer_list`, for unknown number of parameters? Why not just use `vector` and be done with it?

In fact, it sounds like just a `vector` with another name. Why bother?

The only "benefit" I see of `initializer_list` is that it has `const` elements, but that doesn't seem to be a reason enough to invent this whole new type. (You can just use a `const vector` after all.)

So, what am I mising?

Comment: do you have one specific situation in mind? ("just use a `vector` and be done with it"... with what?). in order to use a `vector` of elements you first have to fill it up by repeated calls to `push_back`, while an `initializer_list` allows you to specify a list of elements directly in place.

Comment: @AndyProwl `std::vector<std::string> v = {"foo", "bar"};` works fine.

Comment: Note that you probably should not impersonate another person. If your real name happens to be "Dennis Ritchie" (and you are not the co-inventor of the C language, which I suspect is the case because dmr has access to the C++ language standardization committee), you might want to change it to something like "Dennis Ritchie (not the famous one)".

Comment: @DennisRitchie: sure it does, that expression is using an `initializer_list` to initialize the vector

Comment: @AndyProwl Ah, thanks. I wasn't aware of this before!

Comment: In fact, Dennis Ritchie is dead (The famous one).

Comment: @DennisRitchie: A decade or so from now on, no one is going to remember the exact date/year when Dennis Ritchie(the famous one)passed away but your comments and posts on the forum will remain active and visible and future users might mistake them coming from Dennis Ritchie(the famous one). Its not the present but the future that might be affected.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is a sort of contract between the programmer and the compiler. The programmer says `{1,2,3,4}`, and the compiler creates an object of type `initializer_list<int>` out of it, containing the same sequence of elements in it. This contract is a requirement imposed by the language specification on the compiler implementation.

That means, it is not the programmer who creates manually such an object but it is the compiler which creates the object, and pass that object to function which takes `initializer_list<int>` as argument.

The `std::vector` implementation takes advantage of this contract, and therefore it defines a constructor which takes `initializer_list<T>` as argument, so that it could initialize itself with the elements in the initializer-list.

Now **suppose for a while** that the `std::vector` doesn't have any constructor that takes `std::initializer_list<T>` as argument, then you would get this:

```
 void f(std::initializer_list<int> const &items);
 void g(std::vector<int> const &items);

 f({1,2,3,4}); //okay
 g({1,2,3,4}); //error (as per the assumption)
```

As per the assumption, since `std::vector` doesn't have constructor that takes `std::initializer_list<T>` as argument, which *implies* you cannot pass `{1,2,3,4}` as argument to `g()` as shown above, because the compiler *cannot* create an instance of `std::vector` out of the expression `{1,2,3,4}` **directly**. It is because no such contract is ever made between programmer and the compiler, and imposed by the language. It is *through* `std::initializer_list`, the `std::vector` is able to create itself out of expression `{1,2,3,4}`.

Now you will understand that `std::initializer_list` can be used wherever you need an expression of the form of `{value1, value2, ...., valueN}`. It is why other containers from the Standard library also define constructor that takes `std::initializer_list` as argument. In this way, no container depends on any other container for construction from expressions of the form of `{value1, value2, ...., valueN}`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a question to your f() and g() function, does the const as parameter make the initializer list and the vector a low level const (which would be useless for inializer list)? Or does it just define the reference as const?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by *"low level const"*. If you mean, you cannot modify the actual object (being referred to by the reference) *using* the reference, then yes, you're right.

Comment: well theres a difference in different const's: `const int *pI = &other;` declares pI as a pointer to a const int (low-level-const) whereas `int *const pI = &other;` declares pI as a const pointer to a nonconst int (top-levl const). So why are you putting the const after the type? does it make a difference to `const std::initializer_list<int> &items`?

Comment: @NiklasVest: `X const &` and `const X &` are the same thing. Search on this site, you'll get too many topics discussing these things.

Comment: This answer explains how vector depends on initializer_list, but doesn't say why we should therefore use initializer_list.  I am downvoting on these grounds.  Other answers actually attempt to explain the "why," and I'm upvoting them.

Comment: @SwissFrank: Thanks for the feedback. I tried to explain how `initializer_list` actually works and how the compiler is required to create an instance of it from expressions like `{1,2,3,4}`. Then I explained vector merely takes advantage of this (i.e how initializer_list are created by the compiler) to implement its own functionality. I tried to explain how `initializer_list` is the fundamental thing here, the building-block, upon which you can implement your own stuff. Just like vector uses it, so can you. Using vector for what initializer_list is enough, is overkill.

Answer (score 25):

Well, `std::vector` *has* to use `initializer_list` to get that syntax as it obviously can't use itself.

Anyway, `initializer_list` is intended to be extremely lightweight. It can use an optimal storage location and prevent unnecessary copies. With `vector`, you're always going to get a heap allocation and have a good chance of getting more copies/moves than you want.

Also, the syntax has obvious differences. One such thing is template type deduction:

```
struct foo {
    template<typename T>  
    foo(std::initializer_list<T>) {}
};

foo x{1,2,3}; // works
```

`vector` wouldn't work here.

Comment: Of all reasons, the major is what Paul mentions about the heap.  Dynamic allocations make STL containers extremely inefficient, to the point of being unusable in certain systems, forcing you to write custom allocators for them in such instances.  Init-lists to the rescue.

Comment: Why not show the obvious syntax differences?  You state there are many, but then show just one--or a HALF of one, as you simply say vector wouldn't work but don't explain why not.

Answer (score 14):

The biggest advantage of `initializer_list` over `vector` is that it allows you to specify *in-place* a certain sequence of elements without requiring delicate processing to create that list.

This saves you from setting up several calls to `push_back` (or a `for` cycle) for initializing a `vector` even though you know exactly which elements are going to be pushed into the vector.

In fact, `vector` itself has a constructor accepting an `initializer_list` for more convenient initialization. I would say the two containers are complementary.

```
// v is constructed by passing an initializer_list in input
std::vector<std::string> v = {"hello", "cruel", "world"};
```

Of course it is important to be aware of the fact that `initializer_list` does have some limitations (narrowing conversions are not allowed) which may make it inappropriate or impossible to use in some cases.

Comment: sorry Andy but I'm downvoting as your answer doesn't explain why I benefit from a function explicitly taking initializer_list as an arg instead of vector.