# array vs std::initializer_list as function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list

I can write a function which take a temporary array(such as `{1, 2, 3}`) as an argument in two ways:

```
// using array
template<typename T, int N>
auto foo1(const T(&t)[N]) -> void;

// using std::initializer_list
template<typename T>
auto foo2(std::initializer_list<T> t) -> void;
```

Is there any guideline which tells which one is better?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414832/why-use-initializer-list-instead-of-vector-in-parameters), for example.

Comment: In the first one you can use the length as a compile-time constant, in the second one you can't. Conversely, the first one cannot accept a list whose length is not known at that point.

Comment: @MM Not sure I understand that comment.

Comment: @PaulSanders try `std::array<T, t.size()> x;`  in foo2 (and call it)

Comment: @MM OK, thanks, I understand it now.  And so, by poking our heads out from behind the parapet from time to time, we learn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are both very different things.  There is also 2 or 3 other choices that are reasonable.

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
void foo_a( std::array<T, N> const& );

template<class T>
void foo_b( gsl::span<const T> );

template<class T, std::size_t N >
void foo_c( T const(&)[N] );

template<class T>
void foo_d( std::initializer_list<T> );

template<class T, class A=std::allocator<T> >
void foo_e( std::vector<T, A> const& );

template<class...Ts>
void foo_f( std::tuple<Ts...> const& );

template<class...Ts>
void foo_g( Ts const& ... );
```

here are 7 different ways to take a bunch of `T`s.

They all have advantages and disadvantages over each other.

The closest to strictly better is `foo_a` over `foo_c`; `foo_c` is only good in that it is more compatible with C-style arrays.

`foo_b` lets you consume any of the others except `foo_f`.  So that is nice.

a, c and f all have compile-time determined lengths within `foo`.  This could make a difference, depending on what you are doing.  You could in theory write a `foo_b` type view that handles fixed length, but nobody bothers.

e is the only one that supports dynamic length at the call-site.

f supports non-identical types, but makes iteration a bit less clean.

All of them can be modified slightly to permit move-out (even the initializer list one with a bit more boilerplate).

d gives the easiest `{}`, but g is just as clean (omit the `{}` entirely).

Usually I use my home-rolled `gsl::span` variant.  It has an `initializer_list` constructor.  And I very very rarely want to deduce `T`.

Comment: what is `gsl::` ?

Comment: @kyb guideline support library

Answer (score 4):

Yakk's answer is very good. Here I just want to give my own opinion on it, and tweak its details for C++23/C++26. First, there's the "non-options" (listed but incompletely analyzed by Yakk):

```
template<class... Ts>
void foo_g(const Ts&...);
```

This one is great if you want to call the function as `foo_g(1,2,3)`. It is the only working heterogeneous option (that is, the arguments can be of different types). But of course heterogeneity is not one of your acceptance criteria. What *is*, is to be callable like `foo_g({1,2,3})`. This one is not callable like that.

Many other signatures are non-options because of how template type deduction works:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void foo_a(const std::array<T, N>&);

template<class T>
void foo_b(std::span<const T>);

template<class T>
void foo_e(const std::vector<T>&);

template<class... Ts>
void foo_f(const std::tuple<Ts...>&);

template<class T, size_t N>
void foo_b2(std::span<const T, N>);
```

A call like `foo_e({1,2,3})` fails deduction, because the compiler cannot deduce what `T` to plug into `const vector<T>&` to get a type that is constructible from [or bindable-to] a temporary [of some still-undetermined type] constructed from `{1,2,3}`. Trying to deduce the cv-unqualified `T` in `foo_b2`'s `span<const T, N>` parameter is even harder — which is to say, also impossible for the compiler. [Godbolt:](https://godbolt.org/z/zqqxov49n)

```
#include <vector>
template<class T> void foo(std::vector<T> v);
int main() {
    foo({1,2,3});
}

error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    6 |     foo({1,2,3});
      |     ^~~
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
    3 | template<class T> void foo(std::vector<T> v);
      |                        ^
```

So all of those signatures taking `tuple`, `array`, `vector`, `span`... are just plain out. (*Unless* you have a concrete type `T` in mind, so that you can write a simple non-template function! In that case, see below.)

That leaves your two original candidates:

```
template<class T, int N>
void foo_c(const T (&a)[N]);

template<class T>
void foo_d(std::initializer_list<T> il);
```

There are three differences between these two, as far as I can see:

- Ergonomics: `N` (of a type you get to choose!) versus `il.size()` (always `size_t`). `a` versus `il.begin()`. (For C++26, [P3016](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2024/p3016r2.html#wording-support.initlist) proposes to support `il.data()`. It was forwarded to LWG in Tokyo last month.)
- Performance: `foo_c({1,2,3})` always creates a temporary of array type and binds a reference to it. That temporary, like all temporaries in C++, is created *on the stack*. This means you just used 12 bytes of stack space. If your array is a million elements long (perhaps because you used [C++26 `#embed`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1967r9.html) to create it), then you just used 4MB of stack space! That's horrible. Now, `foo_d({1,2,3})` is also *permitted* to create a temporary backing array on the stack and bind to it; but quality implementations will instead create the backing array in static `.rodata`, so that no stack space is used at all. (GCC is the only quality implementation as of October 2023, but I predict that *all* compilers will be doing this by October 2025. This optimization was permitted by Defect Report only as of mid-2023; see [P2752R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2752r3.html).)
- Template bloat: `foo_d` is templated only on the type `T`, so `foo_d({1,2,3})` and `foo_d({1,2})` will instantiate the same overload. `foo_c` is templated on both `T` and `N`, so `foo_c({1,2,3})` and `foo_c({1,2})` will instantiate two different overloads. If you need to use `N` as a constant-expression inside `foo`, then obviously you must prefer `foo_c`. If you *don't* need to use `N` as a constant-expression, then you should prefer the alternative with less template bloat.

So, `foo_c` wins (slightly) on ergonomics; `foo_d` wins overwhelmingly on performance and template bloat. And, back in the ergonomics category, `foo_d`'s *function signature* wins in a landslide over `foo_c`'s mess of brackets and ampersands. Prefer `foo_d`.

---

For the sake of argument, let's consider what happens if you pin `T` as `int`, but still want to accept braced-initializer-lists of differing lengths. Then we have the following still-non-options:

```
template<size_t N>
void foo_a(const std::array<int, N>&); // can't deduce N

template<class... Ts> requires (std::same_as<Ts, int> && ...)
void foo_f(const std::tuple<Ts...>&);

template<size_t N>
void foo_b2(std::span<const int, N>);
```

But we have two new contenders added to our two previous options:

```
void foo_b(std::span<const int>);
void foo_e(const std::vector<int>&);
template<int N> void foo_c(const int (&a)[N]);
void foo_d(std::initializer_list<int> il);
```

- `foo_b` is not yet an option, but it will be permitted in C++26-and-later (because C++26's working draft includes [P2447](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2447r5.html)). In C++23, if you wanted to use `foo_b`, you'd have to write `foo_b({{1,2,3}})`, which would create a temporary array on the stack just like `foo_c`. After P2447, you can write `foo_b({1,2,3})` directly, and quality implementations will *not* create a temporary array. So, in C++26, `foo_b` is a very viable option.
- `foo_e({1,2,3})` creates an `initializer_list` (with a backing array that quality implementations will put in `.rodata`), then copies the array's elements into a heap-allocated array managed by a temporary `vector`. This is terrible. Don't do this.

So `foo_d` beat `foo_c`, and `foo_b` certainly beats `foo_e`. Our real choice here is between `foo_b(span)` and `foo_d(initializer_list)`.

- Generality: `foo_b` will happily accept *any* contiguous range, e.g. `foo_b(vector)`, `foo_b(arr)`, `foo_b(il)`, etc. `foo_d` will accept only literal *braced-initializer-lists* and expressions of type `initializer_list` such as `il`. Almost certainly, in practice, your intent will be closer to `foo_b` than to `foo_d`. (Unless `foo` is a constructor, in which case obviously you should use `initializer_list` so that `foo` will be an [initializer-list constructor](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#def:initializer-list_constructor), full stop.)
- Portability: `foo_b` is accepted by libc++ 18, but not yet by libstdc++ or MS STL. Once vendors implement P2447, they'll still likely support `foo_b` only in C++26 and later, not in C++20 or C++23. This means you won't be able to use `foo_b` in new code for a long time yet.

---

Conclusion: Accepting a *braced-initializer-list*? Use `initializer_list`!